# Laravel cookie is always deleted

Tags: laravel, cookies

Cookies always seem to be deleted.

```
$cookie->queue($cookie->make('emailcookie', 'email', 129600));

die(cookie('emailcookie'));
```

This is the result:

```
emailcookie=deleted; expires=Tue, 04-Jul-2017 12:37:14 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; httponly
```

Not sure what is going wrong here?

Comment: Expires 4th of july 2017... that's last year.

Comment: Yea I didn't get it either. I've just decided to go with PHP's built-in cookie methods. They are working fine.